# Difference between @After and @AfterThrowing in AspectJ

Tags: java, log4j, aspectj

I cannot understand why advice `@After` is applied instead of `@AfterThrowing` in this situation:

```
    @Pointcut("execution(* componentB.Bye.run())")
    public void newThread(){
    }

    @After("newThread()")
    public void cokolwiek2(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        report(joinPoint);
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="newThread()",throwing="e")
public void itsAFoo(JoinPoint joinPoint, RemoteException e) {
        logger.error(joinPoint.getSignature().toLongString() + " exception here!");
}
```

I am sure that exception is thrown in:

```
public String greeting(String c) throws RemoteException,
        InterruptedException {
    throw new RemoteException();
    //return "Good morning!";
}
```

But there is no log with `exception here!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointcut `execution(* componentB.Bye.run())` doesn't cover method `public String greeting(String c)`.

The difference between `@After` and `@AfterThrowing` is that `@AfterThrowing` is called only when an exception occurred, while `@After` is called either if an exception was thrown or the method returned successfully. So if there is an exception and you have both advises, both of them will be executed.

Comment: That's true. Couldn't Aspect `see`it if `greeting()` is called in `Bye.run()`?

Comment: No, but if Bye.run also throws the exception then you should see 'Bye.run.. exception here!'